# How does android retain view state across fragment detach/attach

Tags: android, tabs, state, fragment

I have a tab host control that is loading tabs using fragments.

Each time a tab is switched it detaches the old fragment and attaches the new fragment.

I noticed that the OnCreateView method is called during this process, and that a lot of my state is getting lost since it recreates the view each time.  However I noticed that some view state such as the value of edit text is being maintained across detach/attach.

I'm wondering how Android is automagically restoring state when the view is being completely destroyed and recreated as a new view.  The value of the Bundle savedInstanceState is always null when I am just switching tabs.  Bundle savedInstanceState only becomes populated when I do something like rotating the screen.

as far as I can tell this restoring of state is taking place just before the fragment onStart method is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When attaching and detaching fragments only the views are destroyed, the fragment instance remains the same.

The fragment manager restores the states of views that have ids, and the savedInstanceState is null.

In case of rotation, the fragments are probably recreated by you somewhere else (in activity's onCreate()?).

Comment: Thanks I think the part I was missing is that the view has to have an ID in order for it to have its state maintained.  I was testing on some views that didn't have an ID assigned.  Once I realized that everything became clear.

Answer (score 0):

When a fragment is about to be removed from the window (or replaced) its [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) (or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)) method is called. This will propagate through the fragments hierarchy restoring its previous state.